# Azure CustomVision cognitive service export model in TensorFlow is missing files

Tags: azure, tensorflow, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Azure Cognitive Services, aka CustomVision website, to create, train and test models. I understand the main goal of this site is to create and API which can be called to run your model in production. I should mention I am using this to do object detection.

There are times when you have to support running offline (meaning you don't have a connection to Azure, etc...). I believe Microsoft knows and understands this because they have a feature which allows you to export your model in many different formats (such as TensorFlow, ONNX, etc...).

The issue I am having is particularly when you export to TensorFlow, which is what I need, it will only download the frozen model graph (model.pb). However, there are times when you need either the .pbtxt file that goes along with the model or the config file. I know you can generate a pbtxt file but for that you need the .config.

Also, there is little to no information about your model once you export it, such as what the input image size should be. I would like to see this better documented somewhere. For example, is it 300x300, etc... Without getting the config or pbtxt along with the model, you have to figure this out by loading your model into a TensorBoard or something similar to figure out the input information (size, name, etc..). Furthermore, we don't even know what the baseline of the model is, is it ResNet, SSD, etc...

So, anybody know how I can get these missing files when I export a model? Or, anybody know how you can generate a pbtxt when all you have is the frozen graph .pb file?

If not, I would recommend these as improvements for the Azure Cognitive services team. With all of this missing data or information, it is really hard to consume the exported model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Many model architectures allow you to change the network input size, such as Yolo, which is the architecture exported from Custom Vision. Including a fixed input size does somewhere does not make sense in this case.

[Netron](https://electronjs.org/apps/netron) will be your good friend and pretty easy to use to figure out the details about the model.

Comment: thank you for the response and the suggestion on Netron. I will give that a try. I have a follow up question. You mentioned that the Custom Vision exported architecture is YOLO? That was one of my questions, if it is SSD, etc... but you say it is YOLO? I only have two unanswered questions then, Custom Vision exports only compact models, I don't understand how that relates to YOLO but also, can I get or build a config for this model? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Custom Vision Service only exports compact domains.For object detection exports there is code to load and run the object detection model in the zip file downloaded(model.pb,labels.txt). Along with the the export model you will find Python code to exercise the model.

Comment: thank you for the response. You will have to excuse me, I am still learning this stuff. I saw that it only exports compact, but how does that map to Tensorflow. TensorFlow has lite, not compact, and in this case, the file is typically .tflite instead of .pb. Also, I saw that there is a Python code sample but I am trying to use the OpenCv DNN library to consume this exported model. It has an optional parameter to supply the config. If i dont supply a config, it doesnt work, gives errors related to size issues, etc...

Comment: Also, just for my experience, is it true that compact or lite models do not have config or pbtext?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I'm trying to learn it also and stumbled upon no pbxt config file being exported also.